# Why I can't use the BitmapFactory.decodeResource() metod into an utility class (a class that is not an activity)?Cannot resolve method getResources()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-resources, bitmapfactory

I am new in Android development and I am finding some problem using the **BitmapFactory.decodeResource()** method into an utility class (a class that is not an activity class).

So I am doing some refactoring on my code and I have to move this code line:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat_ok);
```

from an activity class method to a method that I declared inside an utility class.

It worked fine into the activity class but moving it into the utility class method, something like this:

```
public class ImgUtility {

    public Bitmap createRankingImg(int difficulty) {

        // Create a Bitmap image starting from the star.png into the "/res/drawable/" directory:
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat_ok);
            
        return myBitmap;

    }

}
```

I obtain an IDE error message on the **getResources()** method, the IDE says:

> Cannot resolve method 'getResources()'

I think that it happens because the **getResources()** method retrieve something that is related to an activity class.

Looking into the old code I can see that the **getResources()** method return a **ContextThemeWrapper** object. I tried to search inside the **AppCompatActivity** class (because my original activity extend it) but I can't find.

So my doubts are:

1. The main problem is: how can I correctly use the **BitmapFactory.decodeResource()** method inside my previous **ImgUtility** clas?
2. Why when I use the **BitmapFactory.decodeResource()** method it take the **ContextThemeWrapper** object (returned by the **getResources()** method) as parameter? What exactly represent this object? Is it related to an activity class or what? Where is it declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getResources()` method is available in `Context`. You can simply do this in your Utility class:

```
public class ImgUtility {

    public Bitmap createRankingImg(Context context, int difficulty) {

        // Create a Bitmap image starting from the star.png into the "/res/drawable/" directory:
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat_ok);
        return myBitmap;

    }

}
```

To answer your second question, see this:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

The `getResources()` method is actually present in the [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. All the inhereting classes also have the `getResources()` method. Hence, when you call `getResources()` from your Activity(which is a sub class of Context), it easily gets called.

Comment: Ok, but what exactly this Context represent? And what about the other question?

Answer (score 1):

`getResources()` is actually a method inside the `Context` class.
You can still use a `Utils` class to do it by passing the context object into the `Utils` class.

Take note that this would create coupling between your `Utils` class and the Android `Context` class, resulting that you will not be able to reuse the code directly somewhere else.

As for the second question, I am not able to answer it thus leaving it to the others. :)